# No margin around photo of the week in the header

Tags: bug, design

I noticed that since a few weeks the header with the photo of the week is a bit off:

[image]

There does not seem to be any margin around the photo from the 3rd line onwards.
Is this something that others are seeing as well? 
If so, could this be taken into account in the next fix-cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it started when I posted up your image and it's continued with this one. We have some custom HTML we can plug in, but it's very sensitive to the length of the text and size of the image.  I'll play around with it when I change over the image in a week or so.

Comment: I made a tweak to it, should be better now.

Comment: Thanks!  So wrapping the entire block in <h2> tags did the trick?

Comment: Yep, cleared out some non-breaking spaces too